# What is the best way forward to conduct surveys on an iPad?

Tags: ui, civisurvey

I am trying to help my co-operative optimze their workflow.

At the moment:

Surveys are conducted during home visits straight into (a very fiddly) excel spreadsheet.
Then when back in the office the employee enters some of the data from the spreadsheet into CiviCRM and the rest is retained in the spreadsheet (mainly because it takes too long to transfer all the data).

Two routes come to mind:

1. Use the Survey functionality to create a form that can be viewed on the ipad - would this then be viewed through a webpage or is there an app available for this?
2. I create my own form or app which can output a CSV file. This could then be uploaded to Civi relatively easy and also easily transferred to Excel/reports.

If anyone can point me in the right direction for how to use CiviCRM more effectively that would be fantastic!

Comment: If you are collecting data in a spreadsheet then you might want to import as Activities, shouldn't take any longer to do for one field than for 20 once you have the field mapping set up. if the contacts don't yet exists in civi, then you need to import the contacts (give them an external id as you do this) and then use that same external id to match the Activity to the contact.

Answer (score 3):

If the iPads are connected to the internet, then you can create a profile form (or Webform if your site uses Drupal) and they can submit it directly.

I'm not aware of an offline app but others may know of one.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at a similar solution for one of my clients a while back, where they were very likely to be offline. A quick Google search (I think I searched for 'offline forms iOS' or somesuch) revealed that there are plenty of relatively low cost solutions out there that will let you create forms on an iPad and save all the data submissions into a CSV or similar that can then be sucked in to your Civi DB.